# How to use filter on the Search widget in ArcGIS JS API 4.9?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
var searchWidget = new Search({
  view: view,
  includeDefaultSources:false
  sources: [{
    locator: new Locator({ url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
    countryCode:"GB",
    categories:["Address", "Postal"],
    maxResults: 10
    minSuggestCharacters: 4,
    placeholder:"Find address",
    filter:{
        ...
    }
  }]
});
```

I'm trying to limit the results to a certain geographical area. I've been told I can use the filter property, but I can't find how or any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter object can have a `geometry` or `where` property. The full specification for this object can be found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search-FeatureLayerSearchSource.html#filter). So for example if you want to filter to the USA lower 48 states you might send in a Polygon into the `geometry` property like this:

```
filter: {
  geometry: new Polygon({
    "rings": [
      [
        [
          -124.60937499999179,
          48.17147426999536
        ],
        [
          -110.5468749999955,
          49.33038796569682
        ],
        [
          -66.0742187500073,
          48.17147426999536
        ],
        [
          -70.99609375000601,
          24.454504932416402
        ],
        [
          -125.66406249999149,
          30.682664491952345
        ],
        [
          -124.60937499999179,
          48.17147426999536
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "spatialReference": {
      "wkid": 4326
    }
  })
}
```

[See the working example here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/XxjmQx/?editors=0010). To see it in action, search "Rome" with the filter in place, and then without.

Note that even if you're sending in a Polygon like I am above, it is translated into a rectangle bounding box because that is what the Geocoding service accepts.

Comment: My search is returning results outside of the polygon (about 1 km around the edges) for some reason, is there any way to force it not to?

Comment: @RedHorse After investigating this more, what is happening here is that even though you're sending in a Polygon for the filter, that Polygon is translated into a rectangle bounding box "Extent" since that is what the `/suggest` endpoint on the Esri Geocoder accepts: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-suggest.htm#ESRI_SECTION3_754130F61997429E9B6BFFF4A118DF98 .. So that's why you're seeing additional results.